# What are the semantics of \xNN escapes inside XML CDATA blocks?

Tags: xml, escaping, cdata

I have to deal with XML documents<sup>1</sup> which contain certain textual data (such as error messages) represented using `CDATA` blocks containing `\xNN`-style escapes for non-ASCII characters of a single-byte character set (Windows-1251 in my case).

An example is

```
<TEXT><![CDATA[\xd1\xe0\xe9\xf2 \xe2\xf0\xe5\xec\xe5\xed\xed\xee ...]]></TEXT>
```

where each `\xNN` bit hex-encodes a single character of the Windows-1251 repertoire.

What I fail to gather from the XML 1.0 specification, is what the semantics of whatever is contained in a `CDATA` block, other than it is "character data".  So, the question is: is an XML parser supposed to process those backslash-escapes when parsing such `CDATA` blocks, taking into account the encoding it parsed out from the document's [`XMLDecl`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl) or the presense of such an encoding of the character data has no meaning in XML itself, and a parser is supposed to return whatever it extracted from a `CDATA` block "as is", and it's up to me to further decode them?

---

<sup>1</sup> payloads of SOAP responses generated by the web service of the Amadeus E-Retail product.

Comment: Maybe somebody didn't know about Base64 as a more appropriate way to include binary data into XML documents?

Comment: @5gon12eder, I'm not sure why they decided to go with non-UTF-8 encoding in the first place: UTF-8 is able to represent Cyrillic (what Windows-1251 is for) just fine, and with two bytes less per character than those pesky escapes.  But oh well... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you to decode them. The `\` character does not represent an escape sequence in XML (and even if it did, CDATA would almost certainly be designed to make that character literal as well).